# Shimano A520 SPD Touring Pedals cant clip out :-(

Tags: spd

got a new set of Shimano A520 SPD Touring Pedals and a pair of 
http://www.polaris-apparel.co.uk/product/SPLINTER shoes

i cant clip out  once in has anyone had this problem before #amature?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to clip out? Can you not move the shoe at all or does it spin freely around the cleat?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle.SE!  Some additional informations would be great.  Have you used clipins before?  Have you connected the shoe with the pedal and taken the shoe off to see how the tread/pedal interact?  Have you tried adjusting the tension on the pedals?

Comment: Indeed looks like a dup. Also, hashtags don't work on SE.